# Construct json from dynamic key and values in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i am developing a web application where am creating textboxes dynamically using the attributes from server. I am successfull in displaying the attribute values as html table inside modal. I need to create json object using the attributes in controller and make two way binding using angularjs. I am very new to angularjs.I need a json using the key and values like
{"NAME": "",
  "TYPE: "forest"} and make two way binding for this dynamically created textboxes.
[image]

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in prop['properties']">
                        <td ><label>{{ key}}</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" ng-value="value"></td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: I have posted answer which will give you hint of how to use `two way binding` in angularjs. Add your JavaScript code so that I can provide you more info

Comment: This is link for directives https://pastebin.com/RVDnNFPU
and for partials https://pastebin.com/VKcp7CNr

Comment: Ok. Wait, I will update my answer

Comment: Check my updated answer. Your code is too large. I have made a simple code snippet so that you can understand the concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put ng-model in your input text element and bind the value to it

**html**

```
  <table>
   <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in prop">
        <td ><label>{{key}}</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="prop[key]"></td>
   </tr>   
  </table>

  <div>
    {{prop | json}}
  </div>
```

in controller

```
$scope.prop =  {"NAME": "", "TYPE": "forest"} ;
```

demo [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YLqyNL)

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng-modal](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) for two way binding.

HTML:

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input ng-model="item.value" type="text"  size="40">
  </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {value:'First Item'},
    {value: 'Second Item'}
    ];

  $scope.addInputItem = function() {
     $scope.items.push({value:''});
  };
});
```

Working code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/KIR7AyoF553STjOx

Comment: Also to construct json ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="controller">
  Name: <input ng-model="details.name">
</div>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.details = {};
    $scope.details.name = "John Doe";
  });
</script>
```

This might i think you were asking for